# how override method getSelectionQtyTitlePrice

Tags: magento

I'm try override a  getSelectionQtyTitlePrice method
I'm created a files
My_Bundle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Bundle>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </My_Bundle>
    </modules>
</config>
```

in PA -> System->Advanced the module exist and is enable
in app/code/local/My/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle
Option.php

```
class My_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option extends Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option
{
  public function getSelectionQtyTitlePrice($_selection, $includeContainer = false)
    {
        $price = $this->getProduct()->getPriceModel()->getSelectionPreFinalPrice($this->getProduct(), $_selection);
        $this->setFormatProduct($_selection);
        $priceTitle = $_selection->getSelectionQty()*1 . ' x ' . $this->escapeHtml($_selection->getName());

        $priceTitle .= ' &nbsp; ' . ($includeContainer ? '<span class="price-notice">' : '')
            . '' . $this->formatPriceString($price, $includeContainer)
            . ($includeContainer ? '</span>' : '');

        return  $priceTitle;
    }
}
```

in app/code/local/My/Bundle/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Bundle>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </My_Bundle>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <bundle>
                   <rewrite>
                       <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option>My_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option>
                    </rewrite>
            </bundle>
        </blocks>
     </global>
</config>
```

but this solution don't override the getSelectionQtyTitlePrice method.
Thx for help

Answer (score 2):

Take a look @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/265060/#t357807

> Since this block is never instantiated you should override its
>   subclasses and in them apply your local change.

So : 
in config.xml

```
<bundle> 
    <rewrite> 
        <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select>Module_Block_Bundle_Option_Select</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select> 
        <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi>Module_Block_Bundle_Option_Multi</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi> 
        <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio>Module_Block_Bundle_Option_Radio</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio> 
        <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox>Module_Block_Bundle_Option_Checkbox</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox>
    </rewrite> 
</bundle>
```